# Is there a issue with sandbox paypal servers

Tags: paypal

Early today in the morning, i did the following code (which worked for the pask week or so) and now nothing works:

```
 public function createReacurringPlan(){
        $req = array(
            'USER'      => 'bennyrefaelov-facilitator_api1.gmail.com',
            'PWD'  => 'YWKQ3M3NXBTZQ78U',
            'SIGNATURE' => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AuVEFUpBu6N8yXkmFksuwwSiQOW8',
            'VERSION'   => '98.0',
            'METHOD'    => 'SetExpressCheckout',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Mark',
            'REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'=>'0',
            'NOSHIPPING'=>'1',
            'ALLOWNOTE'=>'0',
            'SOLUTIONTYPE'=>'Sole',
            'BRANDNAME'=>'MisterSurvey',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'=>'100.00',
            'MAXAMT' => '100.00',
            'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'Pay up',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'=>'0',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'=>'100.00',
            'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'=>'An awesome package',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'=>'This is just for fun',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>'USD',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'=>'itemid1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'=>'MyItem1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'=>'basic package',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'=>'1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'=>'100.00',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0'=>'0',
            'RETURNURL'=>'http://mistersurveylocal.com:8080/#/pricing',
            'CANCELURL'=>'http://mistersurveylocal.com:8080/#/'
       );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($req));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($response);
```

$response returns false...
Till now it returns what it should have, that is the token to paypal to redirect to it, Now it seems, nothing comes back and i didn't change anything!
Anyone else experiance this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `curl_getinfo()`, `curl_error()` and `curl_errno()` functions to find more information about an error.

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
```

You had the same problem and I solved it with code below

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');
```

Comment: Got the problem, it was ssl issues and i inserted the following: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');

Answer (score 0):

svcs.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.89) is unreacheable for me from US, UK, ES and AR

BTW, this si more verbose ;)

```
echo serialize(curl_getinfo($ch)) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
```

PayPal offers some information on PayPalSiteStatus here:

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus